# How to READ Faster from ORACLE db using Pandas from large DB

Tags: sql, pandas, database, performance

i'm learning still how to read more efficiently from an ORACLE db using pandas and the code below shows how i'm using pandas to extract lightning data from our db given a lat/lon area and start date. However, a single query is taking over 1 hour to run and i know there has to be a more efficient way of handling this given my db credentials listed below. I have about 15 of these different queries to run based on unique lat/lon requirements. Thank you for your help!!

```
conn= cx_Oracle.connect('DOMINA_CONSULTA/PASSWORD@ex021-orc.corp.iberdrola.com:1540/domp_domi_bi')
try:
     query1 = '''
     SELECT * FROM DOMINAGE.DGE_RAYOS WHERE FECHA_RAYO >= '01-MAR-20' AND COORDENADA_X>=32.55 AND 
     COORDENADA_X<=33.55 AND COORDENADA_Y>=-98.82 AND COORDENADA_Y<=-97.82 
         '''

     dfp = pd.read_sql(con = conn, sql = query1)

finally:
     onn.close()
dfp.head()
```

Comment: Does your SQL sever support [LIMIT](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-limit/)?

Comment: i'm not sure, let me ask quickly and get back to you.

Comment: YES, it's available.

Comment: There you go, `LIMIT` is essentially equivalent to `.head()` in Pandas. Add `LIMIT 5` to the end of your query.

Comment: such as dfp.limit(5) ? I"m getting an error using it in this way saying 'DataFrame" object has no attribute 'limit'

Comment: No, it's an SQL thing, add `LIMIT 5` **to the end of your query**.

Comment: do i need a comma or AND before LIMIT 5 in my query1 statement above?

Comment: SORRY, the db is ORACLE

Comment: What are the indexes in your table?? What data type is fecha_rayo??

Comment: What is your oracle version?